# How to remove audio from multiple video files with Ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, batch

I am removing the audio from video files using the command (on a Mac):

```
ffmpeg -i example.mkv -c copy -an example-nosound.mkv
```

In my case it's mp4 files, but you know... tomayto tomato. The point is I have many files and doing it one-by-one would be a long process. I did find the following command on Reddit however: [Batch to remove audio from mp4 videos](https://www.reddit.com/r/Batch/comments/8c4dc5/batch_to_remove_audio_from_mp4_videos/)

```
for %%F in ("parent directory\*.mp4") do ren "%%~F" "%%~nF_audio.mp4"&&ffmpeg -i "%%~dpnF_audio.mp4" -c copy -map 0 -map_metadata 0 -an "%%~F"
```

My Ffmpeg knowledge isn't that good though, so I barely understand what any of this means and therefore can't figure out what is relevant, what isn't and why it won't work for me. The first command is simple enough for me to understand, so ideally, somewhere out there, there will be only a slightly more complicated version that lets me apply it to multiple video files.

I can't be the only one out there that's not massively knowledgeable about command-line stuff, so I'm sure finding a simplified solution with a dumbed down explanation will be helpful to many others.

Comment: On a Mac use a shell in the folder. For file in *.mp4 do ffmpeg -i $file -an [other parameters] "${file%.mp4}_noaudio.mp4"; done.

Comment: Ok so the exact thing I entered was:

For file in *.mp4 do ffmpeg -i $file -c copy -an "${file%.mp4}_noaudio.mp4"

And this is what I got:

-bash: For: command not found

Do you know what this means?

Comment: In small: for. Sorry I wrote in caps. Most bash commands are in small letters.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
for file in *.mp4
do

ffmpeg -i "$file" -an -c:v copy "${file%.mp4}_noaudio.mp4"

done
```

`-an` means no audio

`-c:v copy` means keep the same video codec.

The file will be renamed to original name + _noaudio, keeping the extension same.

Comment: With #!/bin/bash at the top :D
Works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: Or in 1 line: for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -an -c:v copy "$(basename "$f" )_muted.mp4"; done

Comment: @dorien -Sure- it can be a one-liner as well. But basename will not remove the .mp4 extension. It will remove the path in a folder dive-down. Which is not the case here. It is still recommended to use string expansion/substitution to remove the .mp4 extension. Else you can use `basename -s`.